# Title is showing up on every page

Tags: titles

I am using `\documentclass[11pt,reqno,a4paper]{amsart}` and this is my title:

```
\begin{document}
\setstretch{1.1}
\title{Some Limit Theorems}
\author{Name}
\maketitle
```

However, the title is showing up on every page. It is showing up at the top of every page. On the first page it looks fine. However, on the second page, it not only shows up, but half of it cut off. I attached some pictures below. How can I stop this?

[image]

[image]

The first picture is the title(which looks good). The second picture is where the first page meets the second page.

Comment: Is it showing up in the header of every page (at the top)?  Or somewhere else?  Could you expand this into a complete example showing your problem?  It shouldn't take more than 20 lines.

Comment: @Teepeemm Of course. Hold on.

Comment: The `amsart` class has on even pages the name and on odd pages the title of the document as header ...

Comment: @user187802 I can't change that?

Comment: Redefine the headers or use another document class.

Comment: Your pictures make it look like you've changed your margins.  But we'll need to see the code you're using to figure out what's going on.